# R how to generate a descending sequence by subject measuring the distance from the next uninterrupted series of a given value

Tags: r, sequence

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to create a descending sequence which is subject specific and measures the distance from the next uninterrupted series of a given value in another column. Do you have any suggestions?

Here is an example of the problem:

Given the following data, where the "id" column is the subject unique identifier and the column "dummy" is an attribute

```
mydata<-data.frame(id=rep(seq(1,3),each=5), dummy=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)) 

    id dummy
1   1     0
2   1     0
3   1     0
4   1     1
5   1     1
6   2     0
7   2     0
8   2     1
9   2     0
10  2     1
11  3     0
12  3     0
13  3     0
14  3     0
15  3     0
```

Generate a new column measuring the distance from the next uninterrupted series of the value 1 in the "dummy" column (notice: I am considering an individual occurrence of the value 1 as an interrupted series). Here is an example of the output:

```
    id dummy output
1   1     0      3
2   1     0      2
3   1     0      1
4   1     1      0
5   1     1      0
6   2     0      2
7   2     0      1
8   2     1      0
9   2     0      1
10  2     1      0
11  3     0      0
12  3     0      0
13  3     0      0
14  3     0      0
15  3     0      0
```

Thanks,
H

Comment: Is there a `1` at the end of each group unless there are no ones like the last group?

Comment: No Pierre, this is not a rule underlying the data. This is accidental in the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt using the `data.table` package in two steps.

First step is to shift the `dummy` column one step further in order to afterwards check if the zero sequences are being followed by one.

Second step is to calculate the sequences by condition that they are zero sequences and being followed by one.

I'm using the `shift` function from the latest `data.table` version (v 1.9.6+) for this task, but you can just use `indx := c(dummy[-1L], 0L)` instead

```
library(data.table) # V1.9.6+
setDT(mydata)[, indx := shift(dummy, type = "lead", fill = 0L)]
mydata[, output := .N:1L*(dummy == 0L)*(indx[.N] == 1L), by = .(id, cumsum(dummy == 1L))]
#     id dummy indx output
#  1:  1     0    0      3
#  2:  1     0    0      2
#  3:  1     0    1      1
#  4:  1     1    1      0
#  5:  1     1    0      0
#  6:  2     0    0      2
#  7:  2     0    1      1
#  8:  2     1    0      0
#  9:  2     0    1      1
# 10:  2     1    0      0
# 11:  3     0    0      0
# 12:  3     0    0      0
# 13:  3     0    0      0
# 14:  3     0    0      0
# 15:  3     0    0      0
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answer. Your solution is elegant and it works for the specific mock example. Unfortunately, it still does not apply to the general problem. I mark it as useful but cannot still accept it.
Consider the slightly different scenario:
`mydata<-data.frame(id=rep(seq(1,3),each=5),dummy=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))`.  In this case your procedure would gives an undesired output=1 for the last row of subject 2.

Comment: Still not there unfortunately. Consider for example `mydata<-data.frame(id=rep(seq(1,3),each=5),dummy=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))`. The dummy for id=3 is (1,0,0,0,0), for this attribute the edited procedure generates (0,4,3,2,0) as corresponding output.

Comment: As mentioned, you can use `setDT(mydata)[,indx := c(dummy[-1L], 0L)]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with base R. First we label the number of consecutive identical entries (with `rle`) in the `dummy` column in reverse order:

```
mydata$output<- unlist(sapply(rle(mydata$dummy)$lengths,function(x) rev(seq(x))))
```

Then we set the values of the output column to zero for all rows in which `dummy` is not equal to zero:

```
mydata$output[mydata$dummy!=0] <- 0
```

In a last step, we identify the sets of `id` which only contain zeros as values for `dummy` and set their entries of the `output` column to zero, too:

```
mydata[mydata$id==which(aggregate(dummy ~ id,mydata,sum)$dummy==0),]$output <- 0
#> mydata
#   id dummy output
#1   1     0      3
#2   1     0      2
#3   1     0      1
#4   1     1      0
#5   1     1      0
#6   2     0      2
#7   2     0      1
#8   2     1      0
#9   2     0      1
#10  2     1      0
#11  3     0      0
#12  3     0      0
#13  3     0      0
#14  3     0      0
#15  3     0      0
```

This solution assumes that there are no negative values in the `dummy` column.

Comment: Hi RHertel, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not generalize to the probelm. If we perturb the example data so that `mydata<-data.frame(id=rep(seq(1,3),each=5),dummy=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,‌​0))`, your procedure will give an output=6 on the last row for id=2.

Comment: You are right. The problem is with the last sequence of zeros. I removed those belonging to one ID without zeros. I think it is  better to count the sequences after grouping, I will try to correct this.

Comment: Not sure I can do much without significant changes, and I don't have the time now. Maybe tomorrow. I think the answer by @DavidArenburg is better. I was too much focused on your original data without considering pitfalls that can occur in more general cases.